# Azure: How to create Standard Load Balancer without public IP address?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I want to run my application with AKS cluster(version - 1.18.14) with the dependency of standard load balancer to create multiple node pools. But, the standard load balancer is creating public IP address. which is not suitable for my application. Because my application is private not public.

Is there any way to **"create Standard load balancer without public IP address in Azure?"**

Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look https://denniszielke.medium.com/fully-private-aks-clusters-without-any-public-ips-finally-7f5688411184 ?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Still doing dry run as per given above link..:)

Comment: I didn't really understand it, does the answer need to spend a lot of time trying?

Comment: I'm still working on that, and right now it does not satisfy my whole requirement. Then how could I tell you that it is working??..
Once I done with this. I'll put comment here..

Comment: Have you managed to solve problem ?

Comment: Yes..I referred the above link...by using the concept mentioned in that I created the load balancer without public IP...Thank you,

Comment: Do you mean you solve the problem with creating a private AKS cluster? Or follow the steps to create an internal Load Balancer? If my answer solves your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when you create the AKS, it creates a public IP as the outbound IP address for the Load Balancer, and it's for the egress. So it does not affect that your application is private or public. Instead, what you need to focus on is inbound, if your application is private, you just need to use the [internal Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb), I think this is what you are looking for.